# Can I do bulk updates with SharePoint 2013 workflows?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, office-365, out-of-the-box

I have a SharePoint site with two lists:

- list of assets
- list of maintenance tasks: each task is linked to an asset via a lookup column. Each asset has one or more related maintenance tasks

My need: when an asset is updated, this impacts the related tasks. I want to trigger a workflow to update these tasks.

In SP 2007/2010 this is extremely difficult as a workflow can only look up one list item at a time.

Has this been improved in SP 2013, and is there a straightforward way in a workflow to select and update multiple list items?

I am open to other solutions besides workflows (although I don't see what else could trigger an automatic update). My question is specifically about out of the box functionalities, not custom development.

Comment: Can you include what column you want to change? Maybe it is something that can be implemented as a look-up?

Comment: @RyanErickson it's not a simple lookup, my scenario involves calculations to determine the maintenance due date based on the asset characteristics (mileage for example).

Comment: An event receiver is something you can rely on that will get this to work. I know you don't want to use custom code, but I think this is a route you should pursue.

Comment: @iOnline247 I need this for hosted environments (Office 365 or multi-tenant)

Comment: Event Receivers work in Sandbox, which would include O365.  I had a contract recently where I had to deploy some to certain lists.  I documented the options that are available to you:

http://mattbramer.blogspot.com/2012/11/binding-event-handlers-to-sharepoint.html

Comment: Another thought that hasn't been discussed yet, is using PreSaveAction on the form.  I'm not sure if you are relying on workflow for things you can't do in Javascript, but just wanted to throw that option out there as well.

Comment: @iOnline247 thx Matt. Sandbox solutions are deprecated in the new Office, but I guess it could still work, the issue is more the lack of knowledge on my side... As for PreSaveAction, that's actually what I am doing right now but it's not simple (as it's a pre-save action, a Web service tells the tasks to get ready for a soon-to-come asset update).

Comment: The only other way to fire on an event would be within the App model, however you are bound to calling your own web service. Wherever that may be. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The SP 2013 workflows have the same restriction that they can only update one list item at a time.

Although I have not tried this you may be able to use the new looping features to get this done.

Here is a [blog example of how to use looping](http://usamawahabkhan.blogspot.com/2012/10/create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-loop-by.html?goback=.gde_3724282_member_176524340)